# Visual Studio Solution Explorer won't let me use / see new .xaml files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, architecture

i am working on a project in Visual Studio, using Xamarin.Forms. I have a huge problem across all projects, and i cannot seem to solve it:

Every time i create a new item (a content page) it simply wont create the right structure. Instead of putting a .xaml.cs file into a .xaml, it just shows a .xaml.css file all by itself as seen below on Page1:

[image: Page 1 only shows the xaml.cs file, not the Page1.xaml]

It does actually create a .xaml file as i can see it in the folder outside of Visual Studio:

[image: Picture of my file explorer]

The file named Page1 is a xaml file, it just wont show up in Visual Studio.

Furthermore, the .xaml.css file is completely useless without it, because the method

```
InitializeComponent();
```

now cant find its reference (even though it is there!)

Comment: Have you flicked on the "Show All Files" option to see if you can add the files to the project?

Comment: Yeah i did.. i Think the problem is deeper. If it was just hidden then the initializecomponent method would work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking questions related to *Visual Studio* you supposed to mention version of it. Anyway this is not the better place to ask questions about Visual Studio specially when `xamarin.forms` have many known issues. In VS IDE itself you have option at top right side **Send Feedback** there you can take Screenshots & make a video of what exactly you are experiencing, From IDE itself you can directly post your bugs to 
[Visual Studio Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com). 
However the bug you have posted has already been registered to *visual studio developer community*. find a link 
[here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/291298/xamlcs-xaml-file-showing-in-a-line-unlike-before.html)

Hope it help you

Comment: Allright, thanks alot. I fixed it for now by creating the content page elsewhere in the application, now i just have reference issues, i guess .forms is just a bug zone.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem today when I first started using Visual Studio with Xamarin. You can fix it by choosing the ".NET Standard" code sharing strategy when creating the project, not the "Shared Project" strategy.